# Запись в xml файл в неправильном виде

Tags: java, xml

Записываю два новых элемента в xml файл, вот таким вот образом:

```
public static void addFields(String location, Document doc, int i) {
    OSM_Connection osm = new OSM_Connection();
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Node childNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("xmlUser").item(i);

        Element latitude = doc.createElement("latitude");
        Element longitude = doc.createElement("longitude");

        if (location != " ") {
            paramList = osm.getParameters(location);
            latitude.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(paramList.get(0)));
            childNode.appendChild(latitude);

            longitude.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(paramList.get(1)));
            childNode.appendChild(longitude);
          }
       }
```

Код сохранения:

```
public static void saveXML(Document doc) {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
            .newInstance();
    Transformer transformer;

    try {
        transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult((filePath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);
        System.out.println(" Done");

    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 

}
```

Все вроде хорошо но получается вот так:

```
<xmlUser>
  <id>44119109</id>
  <name>bengibsonphoto</name>
  <location>London</location>
  <url>http://www.BENGIBSONPHOTO.com</url>
  <isGeoEnabled>true</isGeoEnabled>
  <latitude>51.5073219</latitude><longitude>-0.1276474</longitude></xmlUser>

<xmlUser>
  <id>2914403805</id>
  <name>zuccolotto33</name>
  <location/>
  <isGeoEnabled>true</isGeoEnabled>
  <latitude>0</latitude><longitude>0</longitude></xmlUser>

<xmlUser>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста может кто сталкивался как сделать ровный вид?
Что бы каждый элемент был с новой строчки.

Comment: Неважно, как вы добавляете элементы. Важно, как вы сохраняете документ в файл. Покажите код сохранения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно задать [свойство](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#setOutputProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.transform(source, result);
```